# The error with Estimator primitive due to the qiskit version

Tags: qiskit

The code that I follow is from [this tutorial](https://github.com/mberna/qce22-qiskit-runtime-tutorial/blob/main/docs/tutorials/Building%20algorithms%20with%20Qiskit%20Runtime.ipynb).
But there are some errors due to the version of qiskit on the Estimator primitive

```
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
estimator = Estimator([qc], [H]) 
e_result = estimator([qc], [H], [theta])
print(e_result)
```

This is easy to solve when I fixed it by add estimator attribute like this one

```
from qiskit.primitives import Estimator
estimator = Estimator([qc], [H]) 
e_result = estimator.run([qc], [H], [theta])
print(e_result.result())`
```

But there is a problem  I need your help with regarding the minimize by SPSA, I can't know how to variable the objective. I have tried to add an attribute run on the estimator but now it doesn't work

```
# define objective as expectation value of Hamiltonian with circuit ansatz

objective = lambda x: estimator.run([qc], [H], [x]).values[0]

# instantiate optimizer

from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import SPSA
optimizer = SPSA(maxiter=500)

# define initial values for our circuit parameters
x0 = np.random.rand(qc.num_parameters)

# minimize the objective function
result = optimizer.minimize(objective, x0=x0)

# store ground state parameters for later
ground_state_params = result.x

# print the resulting ground state energy
print(result.fun)
```

Here is the error

```
    Output exceeds the size limit. Open the full output data in a text editor
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
d:\Book store\Learning document\QC\Code\qce22-qiskit-runtime-tutorial-main\docs\tutorials\Building algorithms with Qiskit Runtime.ipynb Cell 24 in <cell line: 5>()
      2 x0 = np.random.rand(qc.num_parameters)
      4 # minimize the objective function
----> 5 result = optimizer.minimize(objective, x0=x0)
      7 # store ground state parameters for later
      8 ground_state_params = result.x

File c:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\algorithms\optimizers\spsa.py:512, in SPSA.minimize(self, fun, x0, jac, bounds)
    502 def minimize(
    503     self,
    504     fun: Callable[[POINT], float],
   (...)
    509     # ensure learning rate and perturbation are correctly set: either none or both
    510     # this happens only here because for the calibration the loss function is required
    511     if self.learning_rate is None and self.perturbation is None:
--> 512         get_eta, get_eps = self.calibrate(fun, x0, max_evals_grouped=self._max_evals_grouped)
    513     else:
    514         get_eta, get_eps = _validate_pert_and_learningrate(
    515             self.perturbation, self.learning_rate
    516         )

File c:\Users\DELL\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\qiskit\algorithms\optimizers\spsa.py:333, in SPSA.calibrate(loss, initial_point, c, stability_constant, target_magnitude, alpha, gamma, modelspace, max_evals_grouped)
    330     pert = bernoulli_perturbation(dim)
...
d:\Book store\Learning document\QC\Code\qce22-qiskit-runtime-tutorial-main\docs\tutorials\Building algorithms with Qiskit Runtime.ipynb Cell 24 in <lambda>(x)
      1 # define objective as expectation value of Hamiltonian with circuit ansatz
----> 3 objective = lambda x: estimator.run([qc], [H], [x]).values[0]

AttributeError: 'PrimitiveJob' object has no attribute 'values'
```

Please help me know if you have the answer, thanks

Comment: I don't see the difference between your first two blocks of code. Also, can you put the error you're getting when running this code, along with the version of qiskit you're using please?

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad, you can check it, I just add attribute to the estimator

Comment: Thanks! Put the error you get with your last code and your qiskit version and we will surely be able to help you then!

Comment: yah, I forgot, sorry

Comment: I think you're missing a `result` method call. Can you try to transform this line: `objective = lambda x: estimator.run([qc], [H], [x]).values[0]` to this: `objective = lambda x: estimator.run([qc], [H], [x]).result().values[0]`?

Comment: Oh, tks for your help, but I have another error in the other path of the tutorial code 

Comment: I think this causes because the estimator primitive in the past run and returned the result and now it doesn't, so we need to add the run and result attribute

Comment: Can you post the error you get?